# Handling MySql 'time' column greater then 24 hours in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have mysql table with TIME column. Some values are longer then 24 hours - they just durations rather then actual times.

Try to read them with Django ORM TimeField but there is an exception thrown on MySqlDB backend:

> hour must be in 0..23

Django Mysql backend tries to map mysql TIME field to datetime.time python object and then range exeption is being thrown.

My thought was to create custom fields which does actual mapping - mysql Time to python timedelta but it seems that backend is called before custom field is created so mapping TIME-datetime.time is fixed on mysql backend level.

Any ideas how to handle that ? I cannot change mysql TIME column type, just read values greater than 24 ?

Comment: Why don't you use something like [django-durationfield](https://django-durationfield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: it forces you to change mysql TIME to bigint or whatever they think is suitable for duration. I want to keep TIME in mysql